# VSTO add-in control does not appear automatically

Tags: vsto

I have implemented a VSTO word Add-in, when the user install the setup file , my add-in control does not appear until adding it from “Com Add-in” Dialog in the word option

Is there any way to add the control automatically to the Add-in tab without going to Com Add-in?

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add the registry entry (*in your setup project*) pointing to the office manifest (*vsto file*) into the Office registry hive. See [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2010/03/08/deploying-your-vsto-add-ins-to-all-users-saurabh-bhatia.aspx) describing how to do for all users or just the current logged in user. See [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386106.aspx) for registry entries required for application-level addins.

#### Single User Hive

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\Word\Addins\[add-in ID]
```

#### All User Hive (x86 Office on x86 OS)

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Word\Addins\[add-in ID]
```

#### All User Hive (x86 Office on x64 OS)

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\Word\Addins\[add-in ID]
```

#### All User Hive (x64 Office on x64 OS)

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Office\Word\Addins\[add-in ID]
```

Comment: If this doesnot work, it could be due to insufficient permisiion for your addin, How are you doing installation, MSI or ClickOnce?

Comment: Many thanks, saved alot of time for me. Is there any reason why the whole VSTO-Topic is so bad documented by Microsoft?