# C# outlook 2010 add-in install all users doesn't load

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I am working on a Outlook 2010 add-in.
I have already check this blog. [Deploying your VSTO add-ins to All Users (Saurabh Bhatia)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2010/03/08/deploying-your-vsto-add-ins-to-all-users-saurabh-bhatia.aspx)

My test environment is the next Win7 64bit with OU2010 32bit.
So I registry my add-in into HKLM to allusers install in this way.

> Unlike the HKCU registry hive, the HKLM registry hive for Office add-ins is redirected on a 64-bit Windows OS. So if you are trying to register an add-in with 32-bit version of Office running on a 64-bit OS, the add-ins registry will be under the WOW6432Node. The 32-bit Office running on 64-bit OS will always load the add-ins listed under this key.
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\application
>   name\Addins\add-in ID

After install I check HKLM, and everything is fine with the registered values(like loadbehavior, and manifest).
But in HKCU this registry values doesn't exists. If i put them manually the add-in load without any problem.

What is the problem?

My **registry path** is the next:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\Myaddin

**Manifest value**: `[TARGETDIR]Myaddin.vsto|vstolocal`

Comment: Please share the exact registry path your installer creates and the full value of the Manifest key. If you want to install to **All Users** - then you don't need HKCU - you need to get HKLM working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your **manifest value** should be `file:///[TARGETDIR]Myaddin.vsto|vstolocal` (*[VSTO Fastpath formatted](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2010/11/30/performance-improvements-coming-soon-to-a-service-pack-near-you-stephen-peters.aspx)*). The **registry path** you have is [correct for x86 Office on an x64 OS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8606087/175679).

Comment: I tired, what you suggested but unfortunately it doesn't load after a successful install, and Add-in doesn't not exists in Com add-in list in Outlook.
I checked Loadbehavior value in the correct registry path and this value is 3.

Comment: OK. I tried to find a solution, but I lost. I would be greatful, If somebody could make a sample Hello Word Outlook 2010 add-in with corrects options for install all users on Windows 7. Thx

Comment: OK, it is working. Your suggestion is working. It was my fault, a liitle mistake...

Answer (score 0):

You should check the names of the registry that you are creating. I had myself stuck for days on the same issue, later to find that I had typo on DWORD "loadbehavior" instead of "LoadBehavior"